# JavaFX ImageView Transition

Tags: javafx, imageview

I'm trying to create image gallery and use some image animations. Problem is with ImageView. I would like to `play() RotateTransition` from some method and call this method any time but it's not working at all. There should be some issue with threads but even if it is called from new thread nothing is happening. Is there any solution how to work with `ImageView` and `Transitions` generally?

```
public class ImageGallery extends ImageView{
    RotateTransition rt;

    public ImageGallery() {
        setImage(new Image("/img/01.jpg"));
        setPreserveRatio(true);

        rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(800), this);
        rt.setByAngle(90);

        //this works but not what I need 
        //fitWidthProperty().addListener(e -> rt.play()); 
    }

    public void rotateRight(){
        rt.play(); //nothing

        //run later is not working too 
        //Platform.runLater(new ViewTransition(this));
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add relevant code snippets of what you have tried.

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are creating the `ImageGallery` and calling the method `rotateRight()`?

Comment: I just create new `ImageGallery` object and call `imageGallery.rotateRight()` just that.

Comment: Do you add it to a layout and then to the scene? Make sure that you call `imageGallery.rotateRight()` after `stage.show()` so as to give it enough time to show the transition.

Comment: Yea I do. It's not working even if it is called like this from another object `rotateRightImage.setOnMouseClicked(e -> imageGallery.rotateRight());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per user comments in the question, adding a MCVE

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ImageGallery gallery = new ImageGallery();
        VBox box= new VBox(gallery);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        gallery.rotateRight();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**ImageGallery.java**

```
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ImageGallery extends ImageView{
    RotateTransition rt;

    public ImageGallery() {
        setImage(new Image("http://jaxenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/javafx.1.png"));
        setPreserveRatio(true);
        rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(800), this);
        rt.setByAngle(90);
    }

    public void rotateRight(){
        rt.play();
    }
}
```